# How would I loop through JSON and then sort a response by the key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

For instance I would like to loop through the JSON below, and then push only a home_team_conference if it has the string of Southeastern. I want to be able to sort by home_team_conference so that I can use each array on a separate page of my website. Right now I'm looping through the whole JSON document but it's returning all of them and I'd like to prevent that. I've searched this website and some others but I can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas?

```
{
id: "771",
api_id: "08183e9c-8abe-43a0-871e-b07a53a399f0",
status: "scheduled",
scheduled: "2017-11-22 12:00:00",
conference_game: false,
game_time_date: "2017-11-22",
game_time_hour: "12:00pm",
home_team: "Volunteers",
away_team: "Boilermakers",
venue: "Imperial Arena",
broadcast_network: "ESPN2",
broadcast_internet: "WatchESPN",
home_team_conference: "Southeastern",
away_team_conference: "Big Ten",
home_team_division: "NCAA Division I",
away_team_division: "NCAA Division I",
total_points_bet: 0
},
{
id: "772",
api_id: "342d431c-bcf0-4214-a868-40ebaae75feb",
status: "scheduled",
scheduled: "2017-11-22 13:00:00",
conference_game: false,
game_time_date: "2017-11-22",
game_time_hour: "1:00pm",
home_team: "Pioneers",
away_team: "Mariners",
venue: "William H. Pitt Center",
broadcast_network: "",
broadcast_internet: "",
home_team_conference: "Northeast",
away_team_conference: "New England Collegiate Conference",
home_team_division: "NCAA Division I",
away_team_division: "NCAA Division III",
total_points_bet: 0
},
```

Right now I'm doing this to loop through:

```
var test = [];
    // This gets the game JSON and returns it so you can use it below.
    function getGames(){
        return $.getJSON('https://--------------.--------.com/dbdata/gameday/division');
    }
    getGames().done(function(results){
        $.each(results, function (i, gameData){
            $.each(gameData, function(key, game){
            test.push(game);
            var gameId = game.id;
            var homeTeam = game.home_team;
            var awayTeam = game.away_team;
            var pointTotal = game.total_points_bet;
            var gameTime = game.game_time_hour;
            var gameDate = game.game_time_date;
            var network = game.broadcast_network;
```

Comment: You seem to be asking how to filter (select certain items), not how to sort (change the order of all items). If you can't filter on the server side, just use the [array `.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on `results`. Is the JSON you show supposed to be an array? (The `[` and `]` are missing.)

Comment: Yes that is included in my JSON, just not here.

Comment: I think you're right that might be what I'm trying to do, didn't know anything about .filter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, is you want to get a list of items from an array where `home_team_conference = "Southeastern"`

This will get you a list of teams where `home_team_conference = "Southeastern"`

```
let southeastern = teamArray.filter((team) => team.home_team_conference == "Southeastern")

console.log(southeastern)
```

I am not sure what you want for a sort feature because all items in `home_team_conference` will be the same same in that list. If you sort the whole list, you can do something like this:

```
// Change "home_team_conference" to something else to sort by that
teamArray.sort((a,b) => {
    if (a.home_team_conference < b.home_team_conference) { return -1; }
    if (a.home_team_conference > b.home_team_conference) { return 1; }
    // names must be equal
    return 0;
})
console.log(teamArray)
```

If you need a case insensitive search, convert both comparisons to lowercase with `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Thanks I think this is what I was looking for! I'll give it a try, never used "let" before.